# Panda 3D field of view (FOV)

Tags: camera, panda3d

I create 3 cameras for different points of view but now I want to change the field of view for each camera to 120.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setFov` call for each camera, for example:

```
camera1.node().getLens().setFov(120)
camera2.node().getLens().setFov(120)
camera3.node().getLens().setFov(120)
```

If you wish to explicitly specify both the horizontal and vertical field of view, you should use the two-parameter version of `setFov`.

Comment: Thank for your return!

Comment: Please consider accepting this answer if it answered your question.